# Windows 10 desktop, stack windows on the right instead of the left

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop-icons

When I switch between using my laptop on its own, using it with my office setup with one monitor, and using it at home with two monitors, it naturally loses track of where its open windows are, so they become redistributed among the screens. The nuisance, when this happens, is that they all tend to be aligned with the left edge of whichever display they're on. Now, where are desktop icons aligned? On the left. So every time this happens, in order to have my desktop icons readily accessible, I have to move every window on the same screen over, one at a time, to the right.

Is there a setting so that Windows are automatically distributed across monitors, they'll be aligned to the right side of each instead of the left?

Alternatively, I guess, is there a way to have desktop icons align automatically on the right?

Special bonus question (I feel certain that the answer will be No): When I'm connected to one or more monitors, is there a way to mass-move *all* the windows that are on the laptop screen to one of the monitors instead of having to do *that* one window at a time?

Comment: Does this [Enable/disable/configure multiple monitors on Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) utility solve your problem(s)?

Comment: Looks like a neat tool, thanks, but I can't add any software to this machine, it's a work laptop, it's locked down!